# waitForImages for background-image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, waitforimages

This is the part of the image I found with browsers inspector and I want to get recognized by waitforImages:

```
<div class="jtpl-background-area jqbga-container jqbga-web--image" background-area="" style="background-image: url('https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=767x/path/s4354a59fbfee63e4/backgroundarea/ibb91266a7f033fa3/version/1529172695/image.jpg');background-position: 54.0833% 41.0025%;"></div>
```

Already tried it with $('.jtpl-background-area'), $('.jqbga-container') or $('.jtpl-background-area, .jqbga-container, .jqbga-web--image') but with the same result, it does not 'fire'. I think it simply does not find the picture on that url...(or I do something wrong as I am new to this stuff, maybe a syntax error)?

What do I have to do now, to get it recognizing that the image is that url/background-image? Any idea what I do wrong?

```
$('.jtpl-background-area').waitForImages(true).done(function() {
    $('.jtpl-background-area').css('-webkit-animation', 'fadein 4s');
});
```

or

```
$(".jtpl-background-area jqbga-container jqbga-web-image").waitForImages(true).done(function() {
    $('.jtpl-background-area').velocity({ opacity: 1 },{ duration: 4000});
});
```

Do not work. The page is loading - but without background-image at all.
A

```
//        $(window).on('load', function() {
//        $(".jtpl-background-area").velocity({ opacity: 1 },{ duration: 3000});
//});
```

works - but bakgrounds popping up too late.

Comment: Still no solution. It drives me crazy...where is my mistake, how do I get a function triggered AFTER my background is loaded?! Nothing works. I already invested weeks, uncountable amount of hours and 'solutions'....I do not find out wtf is going on with the DIV above, need help...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/blob/master/README.md#advanced), you need to enable an option for the plugin to scan for images in CSS properties.

Your code should be...

```
$('.jqbga-web--image').waitForImages(true).done(function() {
    $('.jtpl-main').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: I still do not get it to work. Also if I exchange  .jqbga-web--image with jtpl-background-area  or jqbga-container. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @MichaelS82 If you make a jsfiddle or similar we can take a look at exactly the problem

Comment: I dont get this to work in a fiddle, sorry. I need someone who could explain me what exactly is going on in the DIVs.

Comment: I still found no solution, I am using Jimdo and I do not know how to build a fiddle of this complex thing. Its impossible to me.  I have a given div-class (starting-post). Now I have set .jtpl-background-area to opacity 0 and want to fade the bg-image in after the bg is 100% sure loaded. What has it to do with visibility? I do not get it why it does not work here...